# Pronunciation of "ille"?

Tags: prononciation

This one's been messing me up for *years,* I keep meaning to ask about it.

In some words, like *ville,* the L's are pronounced as L's. In others, like *bille* or *fille*, they're  closer to a soft Y, or almost silent.

What is the rule? Is there a rule? If it's random, can I get a listing of common *-ille* words and their pronunciations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Précédé par un **son voyelle**,

- *-ill-* se prononce en général `[j]`:

  > maille, veilleuse, gaillard, tenailles, abeilles, nouilles, feuilles, failli…
- un *-il* final se prononce aussi `[j]`:

  > ail, orteil, deuil, œil, fenouil…

Précédé par un **son consonne**, il faut aussi prononcer le *i* initial ;

- *-ill-* se prononce en général `[ij]`.

  > fille, tilleul, billard, coquillage, sillons, tortiller, chantilly…

  Exceptions prononcées `[il]`: *ville* (*village*, *villa*, *villégiature*), *tranquille*, *mille* (*million*, *milliard*, préfixe *milli-* et dérivés, *billion*, *billiard*, etc.), *Lille*, *distiller* (*distillerie*, *distillation*, etc.), *Gilles*, *Achille*, *lilliputien*, *bacille*, *pénicilline*, formes en *-illaire* (*capillaire*, *maxillaire*, *papillaire*, etc.), et quelques autres qui ont tendance à évoluer de `[il]` vers `[ij]`.
- un *-il* final se prononce en général `[il]`:

  > gril, fil, vil, pistil, exil…

  Exceptions prononcées `[i]`: *outil*, *gentil*, *fusil*, et probablement quelques autres.

Positionné **en début de mot**, *ill-* se prononce toujours `[il]`: préfixe *il-* (*illégal*, *illogique*, etc.), *illico*, …

Et pour finir, *-yll-* se prononce toujours `[il]`: *idylle*, *syllabe*, *chlorophylle*, *sibylle*…

---

La plupart des exemples sont tirés de [l'exercice 154 ici](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/010.html), pour lequel un extrait sonore est fourni.

Quelques compléments d'information fournis par l'OQLF: [osciller, vasciller, scintiller, titiller](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4790), et [nombril, chenil, grésil](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3531).

Comment: *camomille* en [il], vraiment ? Et tu fais une différence suivant le sens de *pupille* ? Avec *distiller* il y a aussi au moins *osciller*.

Comment: En effet, pour *camomille*, le wiktionnaire donne `[ij]`. Pour ma part je suis sûr d'avoir entendu les deux, tout comme pour *osciller* (et dans ce cas, les deux prononciations sont « officiellement » reconnues, comme pour plusieurs autres verbes dans le genre).

Answer (score 8):

This is a tough rule of pronunciation. If you know latin or italian or any other roman language, it will be a great help to understand how to pronounce those words.

*Ville* comes from the latin *villa*, (notice the double `l`) while *fille* comes from the latin *filia*, here the `li`, hence the different pronunciation in this case.

But many other words with a double `l` are easier to spot: *illégal* (read as `il-légal`, literally “not legal”) and other negations, you adapt the pronunciation from the stem, i.e. *légal* which by no means could be pronounced `yégal` in French.

I think in most cases you will pronounce *-ille-* like in *fille* (also known as the *`l` mouillé* in French, literally the *wet `l`*) but we can try to make a list of common words that share the pronunciation of *ville*:

- ville
- mille
- tranquille

Let's note that only the whole group *-ille-* is relevant to the case. The variants *-ill* (like in *grill*) or *-ylle* (like in *chlorophylle*) are always pronounced `[il]`.

*Feel free to edit this list and add the words that come to your mind.*

Sources: [[1]](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=854495&langid=3), [[2]](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100207150855AA0tabx)