# Prononciation du mot "persil"

Tags: prononciation, régionalismes

Il y a quelques jours j'ai été très surpris d'entendre le mot *persil* prononcé `/pɛʁ.si/`. Pour ma part j'ai toujours prononcé et entendu prononcer ce mot `/pɛʁ.sil/`, c'est-à-dire avec un l final sonore.

Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/persil) liste pour sa part les deux variantes.

Ma question est donc : d'où provient cette différence de prononciation ? Est-ce qu'elle correspond à des limites géographiques ou sociales ? Quelle est la prononciation (étymologiquement, historiquement) la plus correcte ?

Précision: Le français est ma langue maternelle. Je suis originaire du nord-est.

EDIT pour précision: je parle bien de la plante et non de la lessive (que je prononce cependant de la même manière, avec un l sonore).

Comment: J'ai aussi été étonné de lire que cette prononciation existait en écrivant [cette réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/6315/79). Originaire du sud-ouest de la France, je ne crois pas non plus avoir souvent entendu `/pɛʁ.si/`.

Comment: Etrange en effet. Je vis dans le nord-est depuis bientot 40 ans et n'ai que rarement entendu la prononciation `/pɛʁ.sil/` par ici, elle sonne un peu "exotique" à mes oreilles. (Il faut également ajouter que l'accent de Sarreguemines est particulièrement reconnaissable... peut-être *persil* y est-il spécifique ?)

Comment: Cela peut vous aider : http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1304168

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Les mots en -il ne se prononcent pas de la même façon d'une région à l'autre. Au Québec, la consonne finale ne se fait pas entendre (on dit *sourci*, *nombri*, *persi*, etc.). En France, ça dépend des régions : pour *persi*, [cette carte](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/07/06/ces-mots-qui-ne-se-prononcent-pas-de-la-meme-facon-dun-bout-a-lautre-de-la-france/) indique  que le -l se fait entendre dans la plus grande partie de la France (sauf dans le centre de la partie septentrionale).:

[image]

Pour *sourcil*, il n'y a guère qu'en [Belgique](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/03/01/les-regionalismes-du-nord-pas-de-calais-et-de-wallonie/) que l'on ne prononce pas le -l:

[image]

Comment: Super les cartes! Je ne me rendais pas compte combien de gens prononcent mal tous ces mots! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Que ce soit dans le Robert *[pɛRsi]*, le Larousse *[pɛRsi]*, le Littré *[pèr-si]*, il est indiqué la prononciation sans **l** final.
Je dois dire que je n'ai que très rarement entendu (sauf peut-être sur le ton de la plaisanterie) quelqu'un prononcer le **l** final.

Comment: Intéressant. Pour moi c'est l'inverse ! Je ne peux m'imaginer quelqu'un dire "persi", sauf peut-être pour plaisanter. D'où viens-tu (si ce n'est pas trop indiscret) ?

Comment: C'est intéressant de voir que les dictionnaires ne relatent pas la deuxième prononciation. Il faut dire qu'ils sont écrits à Paris où ils ne prononcent pas les 'l' comme dans l'est de la France. Donc "persi", "fusi"...

Comment: @Reg: Je suis parisien mais j'ai vécu quelques temps dans le Limousin et en Bourgogne.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu la prononciation du l final et c'est la cas pour la plupart des mots avec cette terminaison (baril, fusil, etc). Je suis du Québec, en campagne.

Comment: Je me souviens d'avoir entendu il y a fort longtemps Roger Pierre racontant une histoire de "goupi" et me demandant de quoi il pouvait bien s'agir... Un "goupil" bien sûr! (avec un l à la fin, comme le sourcil, le nombril et le persil).

Answer (score 4):

Ils prononcent les 'l' de beaucoup de mots dans le sud de la France.

Par exemple, un «fusil» peut être prononcé avec un 'l' sonore dans le sud !

D'autres mots qui varient ou non:

Mots dont je (originaire de l'est de la France) prononce le 'l':

- un baril
- un cil
- un coutil
- un fenil
- un fournil
- un goupil
- un nombril
- un sourcil
- un terril

Mots dont je ne prononce pas le 'l':

- un fusil
- gentil
- un outil
- du persil

Mots dont je ne connais pas la prononciation:

- un frasil
- un groisil

Je ne dirais pas "une limite" géographique, par contre. Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une limite spécifique. Mais il ne semble pas qu'il y ait vraiment une raison connue, ni de règle pour savoir si le 'l' se prononce ou non.

Note au passage:

Maintenant, quand tu entends "Persil" (avec le 'l' à la fin) tu penses sûrement à la lessive. Cette marque vient des mots "Per[borate]" et "Sil[icate]", la source du produit. Rien à voir avec la bonne herbe !

Comment: Soit. Mais je suis moi-même du nord et prononce le l de persil, baril, fournil, nombril, sourcil, terril, cil. Pas de fusil, gentil et outil cependant...

Comment: Merci pour la précision concernant la marque de lessive. J'ai édité ma question pour plus de clarté.

Comment: @reg J’ai un pied dans le Nord et l’autre en Belgique, et ma prononciation s’accorde avec celle du dictionnaire, avec toutefois une nette tendance à prononcer les « l » optionnels. C’est-à-dire que je les laisse muets dans « sourcil » et « fournil ». Seule exception, « persil », justement, où je prononce effectivement le « l ».

Comment: C'est intéressant car je viens de l'est de la France, est pour « sourcil » on prononce le 'l' final. Pour « nombril » et « cil » aussi. Il me semble que pour « fournil » aussi, mais je n'utilise pas se mot... Donc vraiment, pas de règle générale... Merci pour les corrections, je parle en Anglais 90% du temps maintenant!

Comment: On peut savoir lesquels des les mots proposés varient ou ne varient pas ? Ta réponse n'est pas du tout informative. Je viens du sud et c'est plus que rare d'entendre le *l* de fusil prononcé, toutes tes affirmations sont bien vagues.

Comment: @Stéphane, j'ai mis les mots dans 3 listes, mais c'est vraiment juste comme on les dit dans l'est et ça peut varier dans le reste de la France (et autres pays francophones.) Et je ne parle pas des mots en "ail" et autres finesses du genre!

Comment: Ok, ben on ne diffère que sur *persil*. Ça valait le coup de demander, ta première version était difficilement compréhensible.

Answer (score 3):

Je suis du sud est, je n'imaginais même pas que l'on puisse prononcer (même pour un pur parisien) *baril*, *nombril*, *persil*, *sourcil*, *terril*, *cil* sans le "l" final. 
J'ai vraiment du mal à comprendre la prononciation proposée dans les dictionnaires.

Comment: La question est à propos de *persil* à la base :-)

Comment: Si tu as raison mais apparamment pour tous ces mots Wiktionnaire laisse le choix entre les deux prononciations (à part pour cil prononcé obligatoirement /sil/). D'autre part e concorde avec ta réponse à Alexis Wilke: la différence de prononciation porte seulement sur le mot persil.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis né dans le Nord (59), passé mon adolescence près de Paris, et vis en Savoie depuis une dizaine d'année, dans toutes ces régions, le 'L' final était ( ou est encore ) prononcé.

Comment: Effectivement le 'l' est prononcé dans le Nord et non dans le Sud.

Answer (score 1):

En tout cas 100% des chaines françaises et belges et l'ensemble des chefs et maraichers que j'ai pu entendre prononcent persil avec le l !

Faut vraiment être resté enfermé dans sa campagne voire faire de la posture pour prôner que le l ne se prononce pas, dans la pratique si, il se prononce!

Les dictionnaires sont censés représenter l'usage, s'ils ne le font pas c'est eux qui commettent une faute...

Comment: On ne doit pas regarder les mêmes chaînes, 100% ne semble pour le moins excessif. Habitant Paris, je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un prononcer le « l », excepté pour faire de l'humour.

Comment: @Toto, il doit parler de la lessive...

Answer (score 0):

Ma famille paternelle est du sud, maternelle de Paris et du Nord. Les sudistes prononcent le L, les nordistes pas. Je n'utilise ni le français ni le persil au quotidien, aussi je ne souviens plus de ce qui m'a été enseigné quand j'étais petit. Mais j'aurai le réflexe de ne pas prononcer ce L final, ne serait-ce que parce que ma grand-mère paternelle le prononçait ! Blague mise à part, je trouve que prononcer le L est bizarre, même si je reconnais l'avoir entendu.

Answer (score 0):

Au fil du temps (depuis les années 50 quand je suis entré à l'école) non seulement cela a évolué mais j'ai également constaté que cela dépendait des régions, même dans notre petit pays ou une petite moitié des habitants parle le français. Ma mère était Liégeoise, j'ai vécu principalement à Bruxelles et maintenant à Charleroi et d'une ville à l'autre il y a beaucoup de différences.

Answer (score -4):

Je viens du sud et je tiens à préciser à Alexis que non, dans le sud je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un prononcer le L de fusil ! Je ne sais pas où tu l'as entendu exactement mais c'est vraiment bizarre.

Je fais des études en lettres et en effet persil se prononce sans le "L" et il n'y a pas d'alternative possible. Moi aussi j'ai été très surprise ! 
Désormais vous pourrez corriger votre entourage...

Comment: Le « l » de persil est la plupart du temps prononcé en France (je ne sais pas dans le reste de la francophonie). C'est un fait que l'on ne peut que constater. Ce n'est pas récent, il l'était déjà il y a plus de 60 ans quand j'ai commencé à aller à l'école et depuis j'ai pas mal bougé. De plus, faire des études de lettres n'est en aucun cas une référence ni un laisser passer pour décréter quelles sont les alternatives, la langue est quelque chose de vivant. Soyons donc tolérants et laissons aux prescriptivistes de prescrire et aux descriptivistes de vivre.