# Quelles sont les lettres qu'on ne prononce pas à la fin d'un mot ?

Tags: prononciation

Il est très difficile pour moi de comprendre quelles sont les lettres que je dois prononcer et quelles sont les lettres que je dois ignorer ; pouvez-vous me l'expliquer mieux ?
Merci beaucoup d'avance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Le 'e' final (ou suivi d'un s) ne se prononce pas si le mot a plus d'une syllabe, sauf accents régionaux.
- Le 's' (ou 'x') final marquant le pluriel ne se prononce en général pas, c'est pour cela que l'on prononce le 's' dans 'un o**s**' mais pas dans 'des os'. Quelques exceptions bien sûr com 'un fil**s**, des fil**s**', peut-être pour le distinguer de 'un fil, des fil*s*'. On a en revanche 'un a**s**, des a**s**'.
- Certaines consonnes finales, comme par exemple 'd', 's', 't', ne se prononcent pas, sauf lorsqu'une liaison est faite avec le mot suivant.
- Beaucoup de consonnes finales se prononcent dans le cadre d'un phonème (an, en, et, ez, etc.)
- Pour certains mots, la prononciation de la consonne finale est optionnelle (ex: anana**s**).
- Il y a plein d'exceptions, en particulier pour les noms propres, ex: Pari*s*/Senli**s**, Pro**st**/Prevo*st*, Ju**st**/Ju*st*, Amien*s*/Reim**s**, Mar**c**/St Mar*c*; Au**ch**/Allau*ch*.

Comme c'est le cas avec l'anglais, seul l'usage permet de connaître la prononciation de certains mots français.

Edit: voir aussi [la réponse de Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8955/1109) bien plus détaillée que la mienne.

Answer (score 17):

Il y a quelques règles générales, mais beaucoup d'exceptions, surtout parmi les mots les plus courants.

En première approximation, on prononce en finale seulement les voyelles autre que `e`, et les consonnes `f`, `l`, `r` (sauf `-er`). Avec un peu plus de détails :

- `-e` : [e muet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_muet). En français « par défaut », il ne se prononce pas, mais fait que les lettres précédentes se prononcent. Le e muet s'apparente à un [schwa](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa). Dans certaines circonstances (surtout les accents du sud de la France), il est prononcé [ə].
  Exemples : *vent* [vɑ̃] → *vente* [vɑ̃t], *cane* [kan]

  - Exceptions notables : les mots sans autre voyelle : *ce* [sə], *de* [də], *je* [ʒə], *le* [lə], *me* [mə], *ne* [nə], *que* [kə], *se* [sə], *te* [tə]. Tous ces mots (ainsi que les composés de *que*, dans lesquels le `e` final est muet) s'élident lorsqu'ils sont suivis d'une voyelle : *d'*, *j'*, lorsqu', … (sauf *ce* qui devient *cet* [sɛt]).
- Toutes les autres voyelles se prononcent, y compris les `e` accentués.
- `-f`, `-l`, `-q`, `-r` se prononcent, sauf :

  - `-er` se prononce [e]. Par exemple les infinitifs présents du premier groupe se prononcent comme les participes passés : *manger*, *mangé* [mɑ̃ʒe]

    - Exception : *fer* [fɛʁ], *mer* [mɛʁ]
  - Le `l` est muet à la fin de quelques mots courants en `-il` : *gentil* [ʒɑ̃ti], *outil* [uti]. Voir [Prononciation du mot "persil"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7516/prononciation-du-mot-persil).
  - `-ail`, `-eil`, `-euil` se prononcent avec une semi-voyelle : [-aj], [-ɛj], [-œj].
    Dans `-oil`, par contre, le `l` se prononce normalement : *poil* [pwal].

  Dans les finales `-ef` et `-el`, le `e` est ouvert : *fief* [fjɛf], *quel* [kɛl].
- `-c` : prononcé après une voyelle ; muet dans `-nc`. Dans les quelques mots où il y a une autre consonne avant, ça dépend.
  Muet : *banc* [bɑ̃], *clerc* [klɛʁ], *porc* [pɔʁ], …
  Prononcé : *talc* [talk], *sac* [sak], *parc* [paʁk], …
  Exceptions : *donc* [dɔ̃k] ([parfois](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/donc-voil%c3%a0-pourquoi-votre-finale-est-muette)), *zinc* [zɛ̃ɡ] (quelquefois [zɛ̃k])
- `-b`, `-d`, `-g`, `-p`, `-s`, `-t`, `-x`, `-z` sont en général muets.
  Exemples : *nid* [ni], *nord* [nɔʁ], sang [sɑ̃], *cas* [ka], *lit* [li], *eaux* [o], *nez* [ne], …
  Quelques exceptions courantes :

  - *cap* [kap], *sud* [syd], …
  - finale `-ing` venue de l'anglais (voir ci-dessous)
  - *as de cœur* [as.də.kœʁ] (mais *tu as* [ty.a]), *fils ou fille* [fis.u.fij] (mais *fils de coton* [fil.də.cotɔ̃]), *un os* [œ̃.n‿ɔs] (mais *des os* [de.z‿o])
  - *but* [byt], l'*est* [ɛst] et l'*ouest* [wɛst] (mais *il est* [il.ɛ]), *net* [nɛt]
  - `-ct` est en général prononcé : *correct* [coʁɛkt], *exact* [ɛgzakt], *strict* [strikt], …
    Mais *aspect* [aspɛ], *instinct* [ɛ̃s.tɛ̃], …
  - `-lt` est prononcé : *malt* [malt], …
  - *six* [sis], *sept* [sɛt], *huit* [ɥit], *dix* [dis] (et *vingt* en général [vɛ̃] mais [des fois [vɛ̃t]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/pronunciation-of-vingt))

  La consonne finale peut influencer la prononciation de la lettre qui précède.

  - S'il y a une autre consonne avant, on lui applique les mêmes règles qu'en finale.
    Exemples : parts [paʁ], plombs [plɔ̃], …
    Exceptions : singulier œuf [œf], pluriel *œufs* [ø], et de même *bœuf(s)*
  - `-es` est muet, sauf dans les mots qui n'ont pas d'autre voyelle : *les* [le] ou [lɛ], …
  - `-et` se prononce [-ɛ], quelquefois [-e] : *filet* [filɛ]
  - `-ez` se prononce [-e] : *vous pouvez* [vu.puve]
  - Lorsque la consonne se prononce, le `e` qui précède est ouvert : *sec* [sɛk], *cep* [sɛp], *silex* [silɛks], …
- `-n` est muet, mais rend la voyelle qui précède nasasalisée (`-n` en finale n'est jamais précédé d'une consonne sauf dans quelques imports).
  Exemples : *an* [ɑ̃], *vin* [vɛ̃], *coin* [kwɛ̃], *bon* [bɔ̃], *un* [œ̃], …

  - `en` peut être nasalisé en [ɛ̃] ou [ɑ̃]. En général, c'est [ɛ̃] dans les mots qui se terminent par `-en` et leurs pluriels, et [ɑ̃] s'il y a une autre consonne après (essentiellement `-ent` ou `-end`).
    Exemples : *bien(s)* [bjɛ̃], *examen(s)* [egzamɛ̃] ; *dent* [dɑ̃], *hareng* [(ʔ)aʁɑ̃]
    Exception notable : la préposition *en* [ɑ̃]
  - `-ent` est muette dans les conjugaisons à la troisième personne du pluriel : *ils mangent* [il.mɑ̃ʒ]
- Lorsqu'un mot se termine par une consonne et le suivant commence par une voyelle, il peut y avoir une [liaison](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais).
- Dans les mots qui sont perçus comme des imports, on a tendance à prononcer toutes les lettres.

  - `-ing` (qui couvre en fait presque tous les mots finissant par `g`) est officiellement prononcé [ŋ] — une variante [vélaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_nasale_v%C3%A9laire_vois%C3%A9e) du [n]. La prononciation dans beaucoup d'accents tend toutefois vers le [ng].
    Exemple : *parking* [paʁkiŋ] tendant vers [paʁking].
  - Exemples de mots courants : *club* [klœb], *gang* [gɑ̃g], *stop* [stɔp], *gaz* [gaz], …

Encore une fois, les listes d'exceptions dans ce message ne cherchent pas du tout à être exhaustives.

Answer (score 1):

Dans la très grande majorité des cas, une consonne finale ne se prononce pas.

Quant à la minorité des cas où effectivement elle se prononce, il faudra s'en remettre à:

- la nécessité ou non de faire une liaison
- son expérience

Les voyelles finales se prononcent, à l'exception du 'e'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Généralement, le 'e' à la fin d'un mot est muet à moins qu'il ne comporte qu'une seule syllabe.
2. Le 's' signifiant le pluriel est en général muet.
3. Certaines consonnes finales, sauf 'c', 'r', 'f' et 'l', ne se prononcent pas, bien sûr, il y a quelques exceptions.

En conclusion, après avoir maîtrisé les règles de prononciation de base, il est également important de résumer les mots d'exception.

Comment: Hello and welcome to FSE! When answering (especially a question that was asked a long time ago), please make sure that your answer brings some value compared to the already existing ones. For instance, what you said here has already been said here: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8947/14093 and here https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8955/14093 . Maybe you could include some new sources or different, interesting examples, that could make your answer stand out. :)