# Donc voilà pourquoi votre finale est muette ?

Tags: prononciation, histoire, conjonctions, accents-régionaux

Spontanément, je prononce *donc* [dɔ̃k], c'est-à-dire avec le `c` final non muet. Je n'arrive pas à trouver un exemple de phrase où le `c` de donc est clairement muet, en fait.

Pourtant les dictionnaires donnent les deux prononciations. Le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donc) dit « par élision, devant consonne, [dɔ ̃] », puis précise que c'est plus compliqué que ça, mais les cas d'élision me semblent tous contraires à mon idiolecte.

Est-ce qu'il y a des variations régionales ou sociales sur la prononciation de *donc* ? Est-ce corrélé à la prononciation de [*cinq*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cinq), ce que le TLF semble suggérer ?

Quelle est l'évolution historique ? On écrivait autrefois *don(c)que(s)*, donc l'élision est un phénomène moderne. Est-ce un phénomène récent ? Est-elle encore en progression ?

Comment: Mes grands-parents disent de façon assez régulière [dɔ ̃], par exemple dans « où donc » ou dans « c'est donc ».

Comment: Pour ma part, je ne prononce qu'avec un -c. Le TLF est dans l'ensemble assez efficace, mais ici je crois qu'il a un bon 40+ ans de retard (cette partie a été publiée en 1979, et le matériel date au plus tard des années 60).

Comment: Non seulement je ne prononce qu'avec le -c, mais je n'ai jamais remarqué que quelqu'un s'abstenait de le faire (ce que j'ai déjà fait pour _cinq_).

Comment: Dommage qu'il faille lire la question dans son intégralité pour comprendre le titre particulièrement incongru. Question intéressante au demeurant.

Comment: @RomainVALERI c'est juste un petit clin d’œil à Molière... l'emploi de « finale » et de « muette » fait tout de suite sens quand même.

Comment: Au québec, dans la langue courante, on entend presque exclusivement *don*, dans "voyons-don", "don ben +adj", etc. Quand les gens veulent dire "donc", ils disent "faque". (Ça vient de "ce qui fait que".)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personnellement il m'arrive de prononcer [dō] quand je parle de façon relâchée et que le mot *donc* n'est pas placé en finale de phrase et qu'il n'y a pas de liaison à faire. Par exemple :

> Tu viens don(c) pas avec nous ?

Mais je suis apparemment atypique d'après les deux ouvrages que j'ai consultés et qui répertorient la disparition de la finale [k] dans *donc*.

Tout d'abord pour dire que la prononciation [dō] est attestée :

**1.** *Orthographe et prononciation en français* (2006, ed De Boeck)<sup>*</sup> dit :

> **donc** dɔ̃ -k *dev. une voy.* **il va donc à Paris** il-va-dɔ̃ -ka-pa-ri, *lorsque le mot commence un groupe phonétique ou chaque fois qu'on veut insister, tant devant une voy. que devant une cons.* **donc vous viendrez**  dɔ̃ k-vu-vjɛ̃-dʁe, **donc neuf et pas huit** dɔ̃ k-nœ-fe-pa-ɥit ;
>   dɔ̃  *dans les autres cas et spécialement après un impératif* **prenez-en donc**  pʁə-ne-zã-dɔ̃ , **dites-donc** dit-dɔ̃  *ou dans la phrase interrogative* **vous viendrez donc ?** vu-vjɛ̃-dre-dɔ̃

**2.** Ensuite un début de réponse à Gilles :

2.1  Cet [article de 2013 sur un aspect français québécois](https://bop.unibe.ch/linguistik-online/article/view/1304/2184) fait une étude très approfondie des cas d'emploi de [dōk] et de [dō]. L'auteure de l'article signale des articles antérieurs sur le même sujet. Elle résume ainsi la pensée d'un de ses prédécesseurs sur la question qui fait passer la prononciation [dō] de *donc* par une graphie *dont* pour des usages de *donc* :

> En effet, *don* ne proviendrait pas directement, semble-t-il, de *donc* par apocope, mais plutôt du *dont* usité dans les énoncés exclamatifs. À ce titre, Antoine (1962) observe que le *donc*, dit de nos jours « affectif » (prononcé [dɔ̃]) que l'on retrouve dans les « interrogatives et dans les phrases exprimant ordre, prière, ou souhait » (id. :1208), était le plus souvent écrit *dont* dans les textes anciens (c'est-à-dire au XIIIe siècle jusqu'à une période non spécifiée). Selon l'auteur, cela aurait tenu au fait que les nouveaux emplois de « conjonction logique » acquis par donc vers le XIIIe siècle (issus d'une valeur temporelle exprimée, au départ, par le marqueur) auraient croisés certains emplois « plus ou moins nettement conjonctionnels » de dont ; cette dernière unité était du reste déjà « presque toujours [celle utilisée] pour souligner un tour exclamatif » (id. : 1292).

Mais l'auteure de l'article se démarque de ses prédécesseurs en disant que la prononciation [dō] n'est pas une simple variante de [dōk] mais qu'il s'agit de deux mots distincts. Elle expose dans son article avec étude de corpus

> que la prononciation systématique *don*, dans certains contextes ciblés, viendrait corroborer l'existence d'une scission avec *donc*. En d'autres termes, *don* ne pourrait pas être tenu pour une variante de prononciation de *donc* surgissant dans des contextes phonétiques ciblés, nommément devant des mots qui commencent par une consonne : il s'agirait plutôt d'une unité lexicale à part entière.
>   En ce sens, le tandem *donc/don* suivrait le modèle d'autres « couples célèbres », tels *bien/ben* et *puis/pis*, qui représentent également, en français québécois, non pas des prononciations distinctes d'un même mot, mais bien des mots distincts.

2.2 Le *dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) signale l'orthographe *donques* jusqu'au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle.

---

<sup>* Extrait de la prière d'insérer :</sup>

> <sup>L'ouvrage ne reprend généralement que les mots dont orthographe et prononciation divergent, provoquant ainsi une difficulté non seulement pour les francophones, mais surtout pour les non francophones, quels qu'ils soient.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

On ne prononce pas le « c » dans la formule : « Eh ben, dis donc ! »

Comment: Effectivement c'est l'exemple le plus courant.

Comment: Dire « on » est une généralité qui manque vraiment de nuance car certains francophones prononcent [eb(j)ɛ̃didɔ̃K] et d'autres [bɛ̃didɔ̃], ça dépend de l'accent...

Answer (score 0):

En écoutant la chanson de Charles Aznavour (une référence comme une autre !), "Non je n'ai rien oublié":

"Marié, moi, allons donc, je n'en ai nulle envie"

c'est bien "don" qui est énoncé et cela sonne bien à l'oreille

Comment: Bon et pour répondre à l'évolution historique ?