# How is the expression "on est dont bin cute" derived?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec

A franco friend of mine commented on a childhood photo the expression "on est dont bin cute".

As far as my understanding of this goes (being a latent francophone myself, and picking it back up now) I do not quite understand how this phrase comes to make sense. My friend says that in this context, "dont" means "très" or "beaucoup", but all the dictionaries I have checked, do not share in this meaning.

Does anyone know how this phrase arises to mean "we are very cute?".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word is *[donc](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/donc#French)*, not *dont*. This word is usually pronounced [dɔ̃k], but [the final `c` is sometimes silent in some dialects of French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/donc-voil%C3%A0-pourquoi-votre-finale-est-muette). Furthermore, in Québec French (the only dialect of French where the Anglicism *cute* exists), some linguists analyze the pronunciation [dɔ̃] as being a separate word which could be spelled *don* or *dont*; see Laure's answer on the previously linked question. The primary meaning of the word *donc* is “hence, thus, so”. In this context, it doesn't really connote consequence, but rather adds a bit of emphasis and expresses that the sentence is about a particular situation ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donc) §III.A); this is a meaning which is generally pronounced with a silent `c` in Québec.

*bin* is a variant of *[bien](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bien#French)*, rarely written this way, evoking a chiefly Québec pronunciation [bɛ̃]. Here, the word is a pure intensifier, meaning “very”.

The subject pronoun *on* normally refers to an unspecified, generic person: it's an impersonal pronoun. In modern colloquial French, it's often used instead of the first person plural (instead of *nous*), but this is not the case here. Here *on* refers to the person that the speaker is talking to, as in a second person singular. This is uncommon but not unheard of (I don't use it myself, but I recognize it). I (city Frenchman) feel that it's rural and dated; it may be more common in Québec. It is limited to certain circumstances but I have a hard time explaining which. [Rose Sene](http://www.memoireonline.com/10/08/1601/m_pronom-personnel-troisieme-personne-place-reference-francais-classique-moderne4.html) analyzes it as colloquial, and either ironic or affectionate; in this case it's clearly affectionate. “We” can be used in a somewhat similar way in English, though not in exactly the same circumstances (e.g. a shopkeeper might greet a customer by saying “How are we today?” — “Comment va-t-on ajourd'hui ?”).

To put it all together, this sentence transcribes colloquial Québec French, meaning literally “one is so cute”, or more idiomatically in English “Oooh, how cute you/we look!” or just “Oooh, how cute!”.

Comment: Indeed, "don ben" is very idiomatic phrase in quebec, used for intensification (usually with *cute* or *fin*=*gentil*).

Why "(s)he" when the original sentence is about "us/we" ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks I expanded my answer. Here it's actually (probably) a second person singular, so my translation was wrong. It's a strange usage, from an urban French perspective. The usage of *on* as a second person pronoun could warrant a question of its own.

Comment: What makes you think it's a second person singular and not that both OP and the speaker are on the photo, and the speaker really meant "look how cute we are together" ? Your interpretation is certainly possible, but to me it seems way less probable, and I really don't see any hint towards it. In particular, constructions like "how are we today" are typically a bit distant (used to show familiarity towards unknowns), whereas 'don ben' hints that the people are close. If the speaker meant "tu", he would have said "qu'est-ce que t'es cute" (imho).

Comment: Le scénario dont parle @NikanaReklawyks est possible (celui qui commente apparaît aussi sur la photo). Je pense que je suis d'accord avec l'idée qu'on aurait dit davantage un truc comme _t'es don' ben belle_ pour 2SG que avec _on_, quoique c'est pas impossible non plus ; _on_ pour le _tu_ ici serait remarquablement distant, ou ironique, à mon avis. Il aurait été bien de savoir si la personne qui commente est sur la photo et quelle(s) étai(en)t la(les) réponse(s). Merci.

Answer (score 1):

When hearing/reading similar uses of 'dont", I've always thought that the speaker/writer was using "dont" when "donc" might have been a better choice of words: "on est **donc** mimi comme tout!'

Comment: Indeed the person is using the word "donc", only not pronouncing it as you're used to. (Or [using the word "*don*"](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11035/1514), according to some.) They would write it "donc" themselves, it's the OP who transliterated it wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

My grandmother's favorite expression was, "Il est donc valeur d'etre vielle." My best translation of "donc" in this context is "so" or "such," as in "It's such a shame being old."